# Populate listbox with the next 30 dates from current date

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to populate my listbox from today's date until the next 30 days. My current code populates my textbox from the current month. How do I only get the value of the date today until the next 30 days.

```
int year = 2018;
int month = 2;

DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
//DateTime Today = DateTime.Today;
//DateTime expiryDate = Today.AddDays(30);
do
{

    date = date.AddDays(1);
    var dateonly = date.ToShortDateString();
    listBox1.Items.Add(dateonly);
}
while (date.Month == month);
```

Comment: I think you should look at the basics of loops before asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are aware about the limit(here 30 days). Then why not something like this, by using a counter?

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
for (int dayCount = 1; dayCount <= 30; dayCount++)
{
   var date = currentDate.AddDays(dayCount);
    var dateonly = date.ToShortDateString();
    listBox1.Items.Add(dateonly);
}
```

The `for` loop should be `for (int dayCount = 0; dayCount < 30; dayCount++)` if you want to include current date in the list

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable.Range:

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    Enumerable.Range(0, 30).ToList().ForEach(day => listBox1.Items.Add(date.AddDays(day).ToShortDateString()));
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 30)`.... And why use `OfType<int>` the return value of `Enumerable.Range` is `IEnumerable<int>` already?

Comment: Enumerable.Range(0,30) returns 30 values from 0 to 29.

Comment: Because I need ForEach which is available only for List.

Comment: The OP wants to add 1 day for each value in a loop for 30 days. 0 - 29 is not correct is it? And yes, ForEach is only available after calling ToList but you don't need OfType!